# How to automate read.csv command in R?

Tags: r

I'm doing something stupid and I cannot get read.csv to write a lot of files.

If I write:

```
write.csv(X1, file = "X1.csv")
```

Then it writes a ~2mb csv file which is ok. I have around 2000 variables in memory and I've tried

```
for (i in seq_along(fotos)) {
write.csv(paste("X", i, sep = ""), file = paste(paste("X", i, sep = ""),"csv", sep="."))}
```

I obtain the desired files but the files are ~2kb and X1.csv contains only one cell saying "X1.csv", and all all the files are similar because X1000.csv contains "X1000.csv", this is unlike the command write.csv(X1, file = "X1.csv") which creates a file X1.csv containing a matrix of 96x96.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `paste` returns a text, not an object you are hoping for. You may consider [get](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) but I would rethink overall organization, i.e. at least use a list instead of independent variables and use vectorized operations instead of `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the object by name with the function `get`.  However, it is much better to read the data frames into a list than into objects related by having common names.

So you can create a list of the data frames:

```
X <- lapply(seq_along(fotos), function(i) get(paste0("X", i)))
names(x) <- fotos
```

And then write them (and this is what you'd use if you had a list to start with):

```
lapply(names(X), function(name) write.csv(X[[name]], paste(name, 'csv', sep='.')))
```

Comment: `write.csv(X[[name]], paste(name, 'csv', sep='.'))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `get()` function

```
for (i in seq_along(fotos)) {
write.csv(get(paste("X", i, sep = "")), file = paste(paste("X", i, sep = ""),"csv", sep="."))}
```